# How to design the grid view with multiple row in on row template

Tags: c#, asp.net

One of my project I need to design the gridView like Below :

Any suggestions how can i create in asp.net web application.

Thanks in Advance
EN

Comment: by learning ASP ... (grids might help as well ...). What did you try?

Comment: Use nested grid view or grid view with repeater as child to display your child records.

Comment: Try using asp:net repeater as it is more basic and flexible. In your case it can really help and save you time

Comment: I required Editing also so i think i cant use repeater control in side the grid

Comment: So basically try with nested gridviews as advised by Jignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = BOL.GetFilesFromCart();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
            DataSet ds1 = BOL.GetPrintSize();
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1");
            gv.DataSource = ds1;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

For complete guide, refer:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/a577f3/gridview-nested-inside-another-gridview-in-Asp-Net/